# How to add custom layer on google maps using api v3 dynamically

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps api v3..
I want to load an layer that is generated by my .NET code.
I want to display that image on map..
Is this possible ?
Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code..

```
var Layerone= {
getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {

   return "http://www.ursite.com/urpage.aspx?x=" + coord.x + "&y=" + coord.y + "&zoom=" + zoom ;

},
tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
maxZoom: 20,
name: 'Custom layer'
```

};

after this

```
var secondLayerType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(LayerOne);
```

This will create an imagemap layer..
Now u may add this layer on the map as below :

```
 map.overlayMapTypes.push(secondLayerType);
```

Here 'map' is ur map object